# Magento: Block Configurable Product options from showing up in search

Tags: php, magento

Is there a way to block the Simple Products linked to a Configurable Product from showing up in search results?

Comment: yes. dont link to them or set meta tags or a robots files

Comment: I mean in product search, not Google.

Comment: what's 'product search'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change visibility for the individual products. Change it to Catalog only, instead of Catalog & Search. Remember to re-index.

Comment: Is there anyway to build this into the search template or a global switch in the backend? It would be quite a large effort to change for my entire catalog.

Comment: I'd personally write a shell script, that would load every configurable product, then getChildren, and then setVisibility on each child.